# how to find out session id of executing ssis package through SP_WHOISACTIVE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am executing a SSIS Package which contains only one data flow task. Simply `SELECT` statement in source and `Table` in destination. I want to find out session id of this running Package in `SP_TARGET`and `SP_WHOISACTIVE`. I need to transfer large amount of data which would take few hours and don't want DBA to kill my Session.

Comment: The [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at Stack Overflow is       programming and this question seems to have very little to do with that. I     think you'd get better, and more, responses in a more suitable Stack Exchange  site like [Super User](http://superuser.com). Please consider reading [about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too.

Comment: select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions or connections will help

Comment: @SamiLaine this is about MS SQL Server and Integration Services and how to determine the unique identifier for the connection using TSQL or other related method(s). It is certainly NOT a good fit for Super User at all and I see no reason why it wouldn't be acceptable here. If anything DBA might be a useful site but it is about programming in SQL Server and SSIS so it is on topic for SO.

Comment: @Vinayak Is this about SQL Server 2008 or 2012? Your question is currently tagged with both and it makes a difference. Specifically is it a 2012 solution deployed to the SSIS Catalogue? Though it may be difficult to determine this since SSIS can use multiple transactions each of which will get it's own session id.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012 and solution is not deployed to SSIS catalog.